# How to disable "cannot resolve method" error inspections in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have some code snippets below when I use android databinding framework with ViewStub.

```
ItemPostBinding binding=ItemPostBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
final Post post = mDataset.get(position);
binding.stub.getViewStub().setLayoutResource(App.getPostExtensionManager().getLayout(post.getExtension()));
```

I kown `binding.stub` will be replaced with ViewStubProxy when codes compiled. But how could I ask Android Studio to ignore the error here before compiling?

(The error is Android Studio cannot resolve `getViewStub()` method from class ViewStub)

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

I don't know if it was due to my old approach of using android data-binding framework.

```
classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4' // project build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding' // module build.gradle
```

But with the new method mentioned in the [official data-binding guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html), all you need to do is adding the settings below in your module's `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

And the error inspections mentioned above is gone, you can even directly use `binding.stub` without any problem.

```
binding.stub.setLayoutResource(...)
binding.stub.inflate()
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

You can use `binding.stub.someViewStubMethod()` directly but it will fail while compiling. You still need to use `binding.stub.getViewStub().someMethod()`. However, just recently the error inspections is gone somehow no matter which method you add data-binding into your project by.

Comment: There isn't a quick-fix for this? (`<Alt>-<Enter>`, with the caret positioned somewhere in the red- or yellow-underlined section of code)

Comment: @CommonsWare There is a quick-fix but no valuable options.

Answer (score 1):

You are not suppose to call `getViewStub` method this way. `binding.stub` is already the ViewStub which you put in your layout item_post. You should call `binding.stub.setLayoutResource()`

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio can't recognize ViewStubProxy correctly. Just cast it before manipulate.

```
import android.databinding.ViewStubProxy;

...

ViewStubProxy viewStubProxy = (ViewStubProxy)(Object)mBinding.viewStub;
if (!viewStubProxy.isInflated()) {
  viewStubProxy.getViewStub().inflate();
}
```

Error is gone :)